# Which improper integral converges to the following numbers.

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't know if someone has ever thought about some function $f(x)$ where its improper integral converges to $e$, mathematically:  $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx=e$$
For example, I have found this one:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{e^{x+1}}{(e^x+1)^2}=e$$
Is there any $f(x)'$ whith less mathematical functions linked in or out?, can you find some other function without multiplying any constant to it (like I did to my example because you can express $e^{x+1}=e\cdot e^{x}$ and take the constant out of the integral).

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{1+x^2}\,dx=\pi$$

Comment: Yes, I realize that before you told me, but thanks!

Comment: Then, what are you asking?

Comment: As you write on the comments, is there any improper integral (like the $pi$ one), where there is no constant multiplying (1 doesn't count).

Comment: Not quite what you're asking, but $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x^2+1} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{e}$ without $e$ appearing in the integrand...